# Group and Sum MySQL

Tags: mysql

calculates the total price, name, ID of all the products that are registered in a '**products**' table.

this is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
      ID_products int(10) NOT NULL,
      Name_product varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      Price decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
      Stock numeric DEFAULT NULL,
      Supplier varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (ID_products)
);
```

I tried many times to use `GROUP BY`, plus several methods but i can't get what to do.

```
select Price, ID_products, count(*) as Name_product
from Products 
group by ID_products;
```

and the table:

[image: Table]

please i need a little nudge to get out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the `sum` of the `price` per product id try this.

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS total_price FROM productos GROUP BY ID_products;
```

And oh please check your queries, you will surely get an error there. You used `productos` in your **create statement** but used `products` in your **select statement**.